# How to create a List of Abbreviations with \usepackage{acro} that is in the same format as ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I am using the `acro` package to work with abbreviations. I have read the documentation for the `acro` package but I have not been able to do what I want.

In the preamble, I define all the abbreviations to be used in the text, them I call them with \ac{acronym_name}
I have been trying to create tricks to do the job and have gotten this far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%Page Format%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.5in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%Line Spacing%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%ToC and LoF%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tocloft}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Enumarate%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%Acronyms%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{acro}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%Page Numbering%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%Define main matter%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Acronyms%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% probably a good idea for the nomenclature entries:
\acsetup{first-style=short,list-style=lof}
% class `abbrev': abbreviations:
\DeclareAcronym{bz}{
  short = BZ,
  long  = Bienstock-Zuckerberg Algorithm ,
  class = abbrev,
  extra = \dotfill
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand \dotfill {\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .7em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother
\newlist{acronyms}{description}{1}
\newcommand*\adddots[1]{\dotfill}
\setlist[acronyms]{labelwidth = 0em,leftmargin = 1.8em,noitemsep,itemindent = 0pt,font=\normalfont}
\DeclareAcroListStyle{mystyle}{list}{list = acronyms, reverse=true }
\acsetup{list-style = mystyle, list-name={List of Abbreviations}}
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev]
\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Body%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Methodology}
\ac{bz}
\newpage
\subsection{A} A
\newpage
\subsection{B} B
\newpage
\subsection{C} C
\newpage
\section{Results}
Results
\newpage
\subsection{A} A
\newpage
\subsection{B} B
\newpage
\subsection{C} C
\newpage
\section{Discussion}
Discussion
\newpage
\subsection{A} A
\newpage
\subsection{B} B
\newpage
\subsection{C} C
\newpage

\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

But what I actually want is to have the long form of the abbreviation on the left side of my List of Abbreviations. Also I would like a dotted line to link that to the abbreviation (just like the ToC, but I don't want the pages where the abbreviations appear in the text). My dotted line has a little **gap** in the beginning.

Any help?

Thanks!